# GParted won't do anything

Tags: 18.04, partitioning, gparted

I have a usb flash drive with an ubuntu installer on it. I'd like to edit and format partitions on that drive using gparted, but all options are greyed out. Why? there is no indication what I have to do. There is no lock icon.

Edit: I can format this partition to another file system, but I can't delete it. I can also resize it, but then I can't use that unallocated space for a new partition? I can only re-resize the existing one.

Edit 2: Device information says that there is no partition table. I tried adding one and now everything works. Is it even possible for there to be a partition without a table??

[image]

[image]

Comment: Answer to edit 2: Yes, when there's no partition table included in what was written, usually the case with CD images and stuff written straight to disk rather than to a partition first.

Comment: No, there can't be a partition without a partition table, but there can be a file-system, that's what we see in the first picture.

Comment: Did you boot from the USB drive you are trying to repartition? That will always fail; you can't edit partitions on a drive you boot from.